# HTML page that redricts to Index

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have created a Term of service page in HTML. When you visit the page, I want that page to appear. Then I have a small "I Agree" button, and when a visitor clicks it, it takes the person to the index.php.

How can I make this page the first thing that comes up when you visit the site?

Thanks.

Comment: you can make `index.php` as your Term of service page, and have `home.php` as your real index.php page

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `.htaccess` file

1. create file with this name `.htaccess`
2. In that file write code `DirectoryIndex tearm_of_condition_page.php`

Make sure that file name must be `.htaccess` nothing else